# workflow rules use old page layout

Tags: workflow, record-type

I have created a workflow that creates a task (activity). The task is assigned to a user. I have two diffferent task record types for task. I have a page layout for each record type. If the worklfow rule creates the task what record type will it use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow rule does not use the page layout to create the task as the process runs in the background. In any case, if you had lets say a formula on the task object that depended on the record type, the record type used would be the default record type of the context user.

Comment: thanks... and the contect suer is the user that the workflow rule fires under as opposed to the user for which the task is being created?

Comment: That is correct.